# Apollo GraphQL react mutation not updating UI properly

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client, graphql-js

I have an edge case in which my `apollo-graphql` react mutation doesn't update the UI properly, but only if the `edges` array is initially empty.

I am trying to add a new comment reply to a parent comment and have the new one appear in the list once the mutation has been made. This works when there is already at least one existing comment reply, but adding the first one never updates after the mutation unless I refresh the page.

Here is the mutation function

```
...

const queryVariables = {
  last: 2,
  parentId: comment.id,
  sortBy: "MODIFIED_AT_ASC",
};

const [createPostComment] = useMutation(CREATE_POST_COMMENT, {
  update(cache, { data: { createComment } }) {
    const { allComments } = cache.readQuery({
      query: GET_COMMENT_CHILDREN,
      variables: queryVariables,
    });

    cache.writeQuery({
      query: GET_COMMENT_CHILDREN,
      variables: queryVariables,
      data: {
        allComments: {
          ...allComments,
          edges: allComments.edges.concat({ // if this is empty, it doesn't update
            node: createComment.comment,
            __typename: "CommentEdge",
          }),
        },
      },
    });
  },
});

createPostComment({
    variables: {
    input: {
      parentId: comment.id,
      userPostId: comment.userPost.id,
      appUserId: 1,
      content: content,
    },
  },
});

...
```

Here is the `CREATE_POST_COMMENT` mutation

```
import gql from "graphql-tag";

import { CommentFragment } from "gql/fragments";

export const CREATE_POST_COMMENT = gql`
  mutation CreatePostComment($input: CommentInput!) {
    createComment(input: $input) {
      comment {
        ...CommentFragment
        userPost {
          id
        }
        children {
          edges {
            node {
              ...CommentFragment
              userPost {
                id
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ${CommentFragment}
`;
```

And the `GET_COMMENT_CHILDREN` query

```
import gql from "graphql-tag";

import { CommentFragment } from "gql/fragments";

export const GET_COMMENT_CHILDREN = gql`
  query allCommentChildren(
    $last: Int!
    $before: String
    $sortBy: [CommentObjectSortEnum]!
    $parentId: Int!
  ) {
    allComments(
      last: $last
      before: $before
      sort: $sortBy
      filters: { parentId: $parentId }
    ) {
      pageInfo {
        startCursor
        hasPreviousPage
      }
      edges {
        node {
          ...CommentFragment
          userPost {
            id
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ${CommentFragment}
`;
```

Comment fragment

```
export const CommentFragment = gql`
  fragment CommentFragment on CommentObject {
    id
    content
    createdAt
    parentId
  }
`;
```

Why does this work fine when a comment reply already exists but not when the `edges` is initially empty?

Comment: @Jerome I'm not sure I understand. I'm using a spear operator to pass the `pageInfo` to the `writeQuery` function

Comment: just remove my comment. I realize taht you are using concatenate with an object as an array ?